# Plot a tuple of lists using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function which returns a tuple of x and y data, in the form

```
optical():
    xvals = [0,1]
    yvals = [0,1]

    return xvals, yvals
```

I can modify the return value of this function, but ultimately I need to be able to do

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(optical())
plt.show()
```

And get a plot of xvals and yvals.

The behavior I get with the above setup is four points (at (0,0), (1,0), (0,1), and (1,1)) instead of two (at (0,0) and (1,1)).

I am explicitly **avoiding**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = optical()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Is what I want to do possible, and if so, how can it be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpack `x` and `y` from `optical` directly in your call to `plt.plot` using the `*` operator:

```
plt.plot(*optical())
plt.show()
```

The use of the `*` operator in this case is is called *iterable unpacking*, you can read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists)